# Is TCP protocol stateless?

Tags: http, tcp

HTTP,the protocol residing over TCP protocol is stateless and also the IP protocol is stateless 
But how can we conclude that TCP is stateless or not?

Comment: TCP is a connection oriented protocol and is stateful by definition.  Otherwise, TCP could not guarantee in order delivery of all bytes sent via TCP.

Comment: Does the server know if a client is connected or not? Does it remember something from the past while waiting for the next packet (e.g. TCP sequence)?

Comment: So what about HTTPS protocol is it also stateless as HTTP?

Comment: What's your exact definition of a "stateless protocol"?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can't assume that any stacked protocol is stateful or stateless just looking at the other protocols on the stack. Stateful protocols can be built on top of stateless protocols and stateless protocols can be built on top of stateful protocols. One of the points of a layered network model is that the kind of relationship you're looking for (statefulness of any given protocol in function of the protocols it's used in conjunction with) does not exist.

The TCP protocol is a stateful protocol because of what it is, not because it is used over IP or because HTTP is built on top of it. TCP maintains state in the form of a window size (endpoints tell each other how much data they're ready to receive) and packet order (endpoints must confirm to each other when they receive a packet from the other). This *state* (how much bytes the other guy can receive, and whether or not he did receive the last packet) allows TCP to be reliable even over inherently non-reliable protocols. Therefore, TCP is a stateful protocol because it needs state to be useful.

I would also like to point out that while HTTP and HTTPS (which is just HTTP over SSL/TLS, really) are essentially stateless (each request is a valid standalone request per the protocol), applications built on top of HTTP and HTTPS aren't necessarily stateless. For instance, a website can require you to visit a login page before sending a message. Even though the request where the client sends a message is a valid standalone request, the application will not accept it unless the client authenticated herself before. This means that the application implements state *over* HTTP.

On a side note, the statefulness of HTTP can be somewhat confusing, as several applications (on a clearly different [OSI layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)) will leak their state to HTTP. For instance, if a user tries to view a blog post that doesn't exist, the blog application might send back a response with the 404 status code, even though the file handling the blog post search itself was found.

Comment: I don't think anyone was determining the statefulness of TCP by "just looking at the other protocols on the stack". Other protocols were referenced only as a point of comparison. You make the correct point that statefulness is independent of protocols lower or higher on the stack.

Answer (score 15):

tl;dr TCP is stateful.

While Zneak points out that you can use any communication for stateful purposes, the ACTUAL question being asked is whether the *protocol itself* is stateful.

Wikipedia:

> In computing, a stateless protocol is a communications protocol that
> treats each request as an independent transaction that is unrelated to
> any previous request so that the communication consists of independent
> pairs of requests and responses. A stateless protocol does not require the server to retain
> session information or status about each communications partner for
> the duration of multiple requests. In contrast, a protocol which
> requires keeping of the internal state on the server is known as a
> stateful protocol.

TCP's "request" (unit of communication) is a TCP packet.

**TCP a *stateful* protocol** since parties must remember what state the other is in, and what bytes the other has. Hence the [TCP **state** diagram](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tcp_state_diagram_fixed.svg).

In contrast, UDP is a stateless protocol. Neither endpoint retains any notion of state. (Though as always, the encapsulated information could be used for stateful purposes.)

Comment: Really great answer. Also, I love the link to the diagram. To all, looking at the diagram is worth it.
:)

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://www.itorian.com/2012/09/tcp-is-stateful-protocol-and-http-is.html) is a nice explanation :

> Consider the phone service to be TCP and consider your relationship with distant family members to be HTTP. You will contact them with the phone service. Each call to them would be a stateful TCP connection. However, you don't constantly stay on the phone with them, as you will disconnect and call them back again at a later time. You would certainly expect them to remember what you talked about on the last call. HTTP in itself does not do that, but it is rather a function of the web server that maintains the state of the overall converstation.

Answer (score 2):

To properly answer the question, we need the concept of a stateless protocol used to manage external stateful resources. Section 2.4 of http://laurel.datsi.fi.upm.es/_media/docencia/asignaturas/ws-modelingresources.pdf is about a service that implements such a protocol:

> A Service that acts upon stateful resources may be described
>   “stateless”  if it delegates responsibility for the management of the
>   state to another component  such as a database or file system. ... A
>   consequence of statelessness is that any dynamic state needed for a
>   given  message-exchange execution must be:
>
> - provided explicitly within the request message, whether directly    by-value or indirectly by-reference, and/or
> - maintained implicitly within other system components with which the Web  service can interact.

So, the http protocol is stateless, if we consider that the files that are served, the database that is accessed, etc. are separated from the implementation of the protocol itself. A service (which implements a protocol) that is stateless in relation with both sides taken together might not appear stateless on each side, because the other side can carry a state.